# How to have time synchronization work on localtime?

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, timezone, clock

The Arch wiki [suggests](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Windows_and_Arch_dual_boot#Time_standard)

> #### Time standard
>
> - Recommended: Set both Arch Linux and Windows to use UTC, following [Time#UTC in Windows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time#UTC_in_Windows). Also, be sure to prevent Windows from
>   synchronizing the time on-line, because the hardware clock will
>   default back to localtime.
> - Not recommended: Set Arch Linux to localtime and disable any time-related services, like [NTPd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTPd). This will let Windows take care of
>   hardware clock corrections and you will need to remember to boot into
>   Windows at least two times a year (in Spring and Autumn) when [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)
>   kicks in. So please do not ask on the forums why the clock is one hour
>   behind or ahead if you usually go for days or weeks without booting
>   into Windows.

while [Time#UTC_in_Ubuntu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time#UTC_in_Ubuntu) mentions

> #### UTC in Ubuntu
>
> Ubuntu and its derivatives have the hardware clock set to be
> interpreted as in "localtime" if Windows was detected on any disk
> during Ubuntu installation. This is apparently done deliberately to
> allow new Linux users to try out Ubuntu on their Windows computers
> without editing the registry.
>
> To change this behaviour in Ubuntu you need to do the following. Open
> the file:
>
> ```
> /etc/default/rcS
> ```
>
> and change UTC flag to **UTC=yes**.

So, is there any way to make Arch Linux behave the way Ubuntu does with `UTC=no`, i.e. no modifications to the Windows clock are necessary (that is, the hardware clock uses localtime) and one can still have Arch Linux synchronize time (since I barely use Windows anymore but unfortunately cannot abandon it and *don't* want to remember how I fixed the time issue should I have to install Windows anew)?

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43329/863 but unfortunately I can't find something like `adjkerntz` for Arch Linux

Comment: Does `hwclock --systohc --localtime` work for you? You should still set Windows to UTC, better this way.

Comment: @cylgalad That leaves NTP enabled but still yields the DST warning. I guess setting Windows to UTC is indeed better, though I wonder how Ubuntu manages to apparently cope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you *can* use

```
sudo timedatectl --adjust-system-clock set-local-rtc true
```

to *set* the hardware clock to use local time, this will disable NTP synchronization and `timedatectl status` clearly notify you:

> Network time on: yes NTP synchronized: no  RTC in local TZ: yes
>
> **Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local
>   time zone.
>            This mode can not be fully supported. It will create various problems
>            with time zone changes and daylight saving time adjustments. The RTC
>            time is never updated, it relies on external facilities to maintain it.
>
>            If at all possible, use RTC in UTC by calling
>
>            'timedatectl set-local-rtc 0'.**

So, there doesn't seem to be any way to have this work without breaking DST adaption (Then again, DST should be abolished altogether...).